# база данных для swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Хочу попробовать использовать бд в проекте на Xcode, слышал про Realm, но гайдов не нашел, смотрел про sqlite, там все еще грустнее)), подскажите что использовать для swift и по возможности ссылочку на гайд

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать нативные средства: CoreData, SwiftData

Примеры и туториалы можно посмотреть здесь, например:

1. SwiftData

https://habr.com/ru/companies/surfstudio/articles/742696/

2. CoreData:

https://habr.com/ru/articles/303512/

https://habr.com/ru/articles/493262/

3. Realm:

https://habr.com/ru/articles/272393/

https://swiftbook.ru/post/tutorials/tutorial-po-freymvorku-realm/?ysclid=lm4kytuc32444186677

4. SQLite:

https://habr.com/ru/articles/277423/